# while binding my node.js/express application with dbus with express apllication

Tags: node.js, express, computer-science, dbus

I am getting this error while creating binding with node.js and dbus using dbus-native package ? My server is running but getting this error  ? I am also adding my complete code after this error , Please check it and suggest some possible way to resolve.
`node:events:492
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: connect ENOENT /run/user/1000/bus
at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16)
Emitted 'error' event at:
at Socket. (/home/chanchal/development/example/node_modules/dbus-native/index.js:81:10)
at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '/run/user/1000/bus'
}`

```
const express = require('express');
const dbus = require('dbus-native');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3001;

// Set the D-Bus address (replace with your actual D-Bus address)
process.env.DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus';

// Initialize D-Bus client
const bus = dbus.sessionBus();

// API to calculate the sum using D-Bus
app.get('/api/sum/:num1/:num2', (req, res) => {
  const { num1, num2 } = req.params;

  // Convert parameters to integers
  const a = parseInt(num1, 10);
  const b = parseInt(num2, 10);

  // Get the service object
  const serviceName = 'com.example.Calculator';
  const service = bus.getService(serviceName);

  // Check if the service is available
  if (!service) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'D-Bus service not available' });
  }

  // Get the object path
  const objectPath = '/com/example/CalculatorObject';
  const calculatorObject = service.getObject(objectPath);

  // Check if the object is available
  if (!calculatorObject) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'D-Bus object not available' });
  }

  // Get the interface
  const interfaceName = 'com.example.CalculatorInterface';
  const calculatorInterface = calculatorObject[interfaceName];

  // Check if the interface is available
  if (!calculatorInterface) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: 'D-Bus interface not available' });
  }

  // Call the D-Bus method to add two numbers
  calculatorInterface.Add(a, b, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error calling D-Bus method:', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error calling D-Bus method' });
    }

    res.json({ result });
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

am trying dbus binding with node.js and dbus and getting the error which I explained above.